# Angles between subspaces-problem of correctnes of their definition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be linear  subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ of dimensions $k$ and $l$, respectively with $k \leq l$. The canonical angles between $X$ and $Y$
$0\leq \phi_1 \leq \phi_2\leq \phi_k \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
are defined recursively by
\begin{align*}
\cos \phi_k=\max \{ |\langle x,y\rangle|: x\in X, y\in Y, &\|x\|=\|y\|=1, x\bot x_i, y\bot y_i \textrm{ for } i=1,...,k-1 \} \\&= 
|\langle x_k,y_k\rangle|.
\end{align*}

Obviously,  $\phi_1$ is well defined and by compactness of the sphere $S^1$ in $\mathbb R^n$  $\cos \phi_1=|\langle x_1,y_1\rangle|$ for some $x_1,y_1 \in S^1$, $x_1 \in X$, $y_1 \in Y$. But such $x_1,y_1$ are not unique. Why then $\phi_2$ is uniquely defined not dependly on the choice of $x_1, y_1$?
Similarly, further angles $\phi_3,...,\phi_k$ are correct defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are not unique, but their orthogonal complements are unique. So in every step of the process you are minimizing over a uniquely defined subset of the unit sphere. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are intersecting planes in three-dimensional space, $\phi_1=0$, realized on any pair $x_1,y_1$ with unit norm in their line of intersection. But then $\phi_2$ is uniquely defined as the dihedral angle, since the orthogonal complement is a plane orthogonal to the intersection of $X$ and $Y$, giving you two lines of intersection, for which the angle is uniquely determined. The same thing happens in higher dimensions.

Comment: I think that the orthogonal complement of vectors $x_1$, $y_1$ is not unique. |f for example  $X=Y$,  we can take $x_1=y_`1$ as arbitrary unit vector from $X=Y$.

Comment: I think this is a very special case when your max is achieved when the vectors are equal, because they are picked from the same subspace at every step. All the angles are zero in that case. But if $X$ is not a subspace of $Y$ (and hence not all the angles are zero) I believe the orthogonal complements are uniquely determined. This is just an intuition, I will try to come up with a proof

Answer (score 0):

If $Q,R$ are orthonormal bases of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, then the singular values of $Q^TR$ are the cosines of the angles you have defined.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats

Thus, the fact that the singular values are well defined is sufficient.

Comment: Maybe in the proof of this fact the correctness of definitions of angles is needed. Wikipedia does not  get this.

Comment: The proof is quite straightforward. Let me know if you'd like the details. Also, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition "In general, the SVD is unique up to arbitrary unitary transformations applied uniformly to the column vectors of both U and V spanning the subspaces of each singular value, and up to arbitrary unitary transformations on vectors of U and V spanning the kernel and cokernel, respectively, of M." The singular values, and therefore the principal angles, are thus uniquely determined.